# Intellij top level element is not completed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

In Intellij idea 12.1.4. Spring context configuration shows error for multiple file locations
as `Top level element is not completed`
@ContextConfiguration(locations= {"classpath:sampleWebService-test.xml"})

How would i solve this?

Answer (score 12):

I had something similar happen to be in one of my XML files in IntelliJ 13.1.4. Somehow, I ended up with a situation where my file had [language injection configured](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/using-language-injections.html). I fixed this by:

1. `Alt + Enter` - Show intention actions and quick-fixes
2. Select `Un-inject Language/Reference`

Comment: `Alt + Enter` is the _Show context actions..._ context menu (right click). In fact in my Java source file there was XML injected for a simple String. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

In my case alt+enter was not working. 
There were invisible characters, which were underlined with red line - select everything with red line and delete it